# Unable to find the org.drools.builder.KnowledgeType drrols class

Tags: drools

While am trying to execute the Helloword process example from the section 2.3 in

- https://hudson.jboss.org/hudson/job/drools/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/target/docs/drools-flow/html_single/index.html#d4e24 site am unable to find the below mentioned class.

org.drools.builder.KnowledgeType

Could anyone please tell from which package can i get this class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That part of the documentation seems a little outdated.  You should use ResourceType.  I've updated the docs with the following code fragment instead (should also appear on the link you're using once the build succeeds):

```
package com.sample;

import org.drools.KnowledgeBase;
import org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilder;
import org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory;
import org.drools.builder.ResourceType;
import org.drools.io.ResourceFactory;
import org.drools.logger.KnowledgeRuntimeLogger;
import org.drools.logger.KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory;
import org.drools.runtime.StatefulKnowledgeSession;

/**
 * This is a sample file to launch a process.
 */
public class ProcessTest {

  public static final void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      // load up the knowledge base
      KnowledgeBase kbase = readKnowledgeBase();
      StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
      KnowledgeRuntimeLogger logger = KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory.newFileLogger(ksession, "test");
      // start a new process instance
      ksession.startProcess("com.sample.ruleflow");
      logger.close();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static KnowledgeBase readKnowledgeBase() throws Exception {
    KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("ruleflow.rf"), ResourceType.DRF);
    return kbuilder.newKnowledgeBase();
  }
}
```